# Python- IndexError: list index out of range, while in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array, pycharm

I'm new to python. I am trying to write a code to take input from text file like

```
6 6
* o o o o *
o o * o o o
o o * o o *
o o * o o o
o o o o * o
o o o o o o
```

and count the number of "*" near each string and update each string with the new count like:

```
6 6
* 2 1 1 1 *
1 3 * 2 2 2
0 3 * 3 1 *
0 2 * 2 2 2
0 1 1 2 * 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

And update this on an output.txt. Until now my code is taking input and providing rows, column, and matrix but as soon as I get into the list to count, it fails giving error

> ```
> if matrix[num_rows][num_columns][1] == "x":
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

My code snippet:

```
def parse_in(input_name):
    list_of_lists = []
    with open(input_name,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            with open(input_name) as f:
                num_rows, num_columns = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()]

                lines = f.read().splitlines()
            # in alternative, if you need to use the file content as numbers
        matrix = []
        print(lines)
        for x in lines:
            matrix.append(x.split(' '))
        print(matrix)
    return matrix, num_rows, num_columns


def detector(matrix, num_rows, num_columns):
    mine_count = 0
    # For every every space around the square, including itself
    for r in range(num_rows):
        for c in range(num_columns):
            # If the square exist on the matrix
            if 0 <= num_rows + r <= 2 and 0 <= num_columns + c <= 2:
                # If the square contains a mine
                if matrix[r][c] == "*":
                    # Raise the mine count
                    mine_count = mine_count + 1
            # If the original square contains a mine
            if matrix[r][c] == "*":
                print(mine_count)
                # Lower the mine count by 1, because the square itself having a mine shouldn't be counted
                mine_count = mine_count - 1
                print(mine_count)
            return mine_count


def parse_out(output_name, my_solution):
    pass


def my_main(input_name, output_name):
    # 1. We do the parseIn from the input file
    lines, num_rows, num_columns = parse_in(input_name)

    # 2. We do the strategy to solve the problem
    my_solution = detector(lines, num_rows, num_columns)

    # 3. We do the parse out to the output file
    parse_out(output_name, my_solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 1. Name of input and output files
    input_name = "input_2.txt"
    output_name = "output.txt"

    # 2. Main function
    my_main(input_name, output_name)
```

Comment: I don't understand the `for line in f:` loop. You're not doing anything with `line`, and you're overwriting the `lines` variable each time.

Comment: Indexes start at `0`, not `1`. Why are you using `[1]` to read the first character of the string?

Comment: Why are you even using an index? Just write `if matrix[num_rows][num_columns] == "x":`

Comment: However, `num_rows` and `num_column` will be out of range, since list indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.

Comment: You should be using `maxtrix[r][c]`, not `matrix[num_rows][num_columns]`

Comment: Why do you use `num_rows + r` and `num_columns + c`? Those will always be out of range.

Comment: It seems like you really need to review your tutorial on indexing lists and strings, you don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: @TomKarzes, sorry. Updated the issue.

Comment: @Barmar, I have just started learning python, so sorry for silly mistakes. Just trying to figure out how to update matrix with count of "*"  nearby.Actually not able to think of good logical way for this.

Comment: Your file contains `*` and `o`, why is the code looking for `x`?

Comment: Actually, for debugging I was directly passing a matrix with "x" .It is "*" in the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the text file and get the line contents into a numpy array, with this :

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    mat_shape = tuple(map(int, all_lines[0].split()))
    lines = [i.strip().split() for i in all_lines[1:]]
lines = np.array(lines)
```

Read the first line of the text file, split, map them into int and keep it in a tuple as we use it to resize our matrix later.

`lines` would be like this :

```
[['*' 'o' 'o' 'o' 'o' '*']
 ['o' 'o' '*' 'o' 'o' 'o']
 ['o' 'o' '*' 'o' 'o' '*']
 ['o' 'o' '*' 'o' 'o' 'o']
 ['o' 'o' 'o' 'o' '*' 'o']
 ['o' 'o' 'o' 'o' 'o' 'o']]
```

Get the neighbor items for each cell of the matrix, with this function :

```
def get_neighbours(lines, cell):
    row, col = cell
    row_max = len(lines)
    col_max = len(lines[0])
    cell_cont = lines[row][col]
    if cell_cont!="*":
        return [lines[row_d + row][col_d + col] for col_d in [-1,0,1] if (0 <= (col_d + col) < col_max) or (col_d == 0 and row_d==0) for row_d in [-1,0,1] if 0 <= (row_d + row) < row_max ].count('*')
    else:
        return '*'
```

The function takes whole matrix and a particular cell which is a tuple of row and column number. It returns only `'*'` if there is a star in the cell, otherwise an integer - the number of stars in the adjacent neighbor cells.

Now create a new array, and call this function for each cell of the matrix :

```
new = []
for i,_ in enumerate(lines):
    for j,_ in enumerate(lines[i]):
        new.append(get_neighbours(lines, (i,j)))
new = np.array(new)
```

If you now reshape this matrix into the desired format by this :

```
new = new.reshape(mat_shape)
```

It becomes :

```
[['*' '2' '1' '1' '1' '*']
 ['1' '3' '*' '2' '2' '2']
 ['0' '3' '*' '3' '1' '*']
 ['0' '2' '*' '3' '2' '2']
 ['0' '1' '1' '2' '*' '1']
 ['0' '0' '0' '1' '1' '1']]
```

You can write this into a new text file with this :

```
with open('new1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(all_lines[0])
    for i in new:
        f.write(' '.join(i))
        f.write('\n')
```

It would write the following content into the `new1.txt` file :

```
6 6
* 2 1 1 1 *
1 3 * 2 2 2
0 3 * 3 1 *
0 2 * 2 2 2
0 1 1 2 * 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: I tried doing this problem with numpy but it fails as array consists of non-numeric variables.

Comment: @user3863292 Did you try this code in the answer? Anyway, you can always work in numpy even if contains non-numeric variables.

Comment: If possible can you explain what this line implements:  `if cell_cont!="*":
        return [lines[row_d + row][col_d + col] for col_d in [-1,0,1] if (0 <= (col_d + col) < col_max) or (col_d == 0 and row_d==0) for row_d in [-1,0,1] if 0 <= (row_d + row) < row_max ].count('*') `

Comment: While using this method I am receiving this error:  'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row_d' referenced before assignment'

Comment: @user3863292 We are basically getting the elements in the 8 nearest neighbor cell of that particular given cell. The list comprehension includes the element of the current cell also, but as we are doing it for the cell having only `'o'` the returned list won't account for any extra `'*'`. After list of the all nearest neighbor elements is created, we count the number of `'*'` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I get it. One more thing, I am still getting **'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row_d' referenced before assignment'** error while using your code.

Comment: @user3863292 Hi, I just found out the problem, your text file has first line as `6 6` in it. We have to only get the matrix part, we don't need the shape of the matrix. So we can just do the `f.readlines()[1:]` while creating the numpy matrix from the text file. I've updated the code, try afresh once more please.

Comment: Is it possible to `new = new.reshape((6,6))` more dynamic, like by taking the first line of text file where row and column are given and using them in reshape function.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the matrix, you don't need two loops. You can build the matrix directly in the loop that reads the file. You also don't need to open the file multiple times.

```
def parse_in(input_name):
    matrix = []
    with open(input_name,"r") as f:
        num_rows, num_columns = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()]
        for line in f:
            matrix.append(line.split(' '))
    return matrix, num_rows, num_columns
```

You don't need to pass `num_rows` and `num_columns` to the `detector()` function. Unlike languages like C, Python knows the length of lists, so you can just loop over the list elements directly. And you can use `enumerate()` to get the indexes as you're looping.

When counting the number of mines next to a square, you just need to loop from `r-1` to `r+1` and from `c-1` to `c+1`. And you need to set `mine_count` to `0` before this loop.

```
def detector(matrix):
    result = []
    for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
        result_row = []
        for c, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == "*":
                result_row.append(cell)
            else:
                mine_count = 0
                for x in range(c-1, c+2):
                    for y in range(r-1, r+2):
                        if 0 <= x < len(row) and 0 <= y < len(matrix) and matrix[x][y] == "*":
                            mine_count += 1
                result_row.append(str(mine_count))
        result.append(result_row)
    return result
```

Comment: While using this code I am receiving this error:  `if 0 <= x < len(row) and 0 <= y < len(matrix) and matrix[x][y] == "x":`
**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**