# List Index Out of Range exception- Unable to print a list of values by opening a text file in python

Tags: list, python-3.8

I received the following error when I was debgging my entire code base in visual studio :

The expected output should print out the different index values from this txt file.

```
    Korea   7DaysKorea  SpringTimeAdventure 1000.70    
    Australia   10DaysAustralia CultureFun  1100.55
    Japan   14DaysJapan  SakuraSeasonAroundTheCorner   1500.20
    UnitedStatesofAmerica   10DaysUSA   RoadTripNatureWonder    1650.30   
    Taiwan  10DaysTaiwan    AddAroundTaiwan 900.50 
    Germany 7DaysGermany    MustGoSummerVacationFreiburgBlackForest 1200.70
    Russia  10DaysRussia    CultureNatureFunKazanYekaterinburgLakeBaikal    1000.40   
    Ukraine   8DaysUkraine  ExcitingAdventureKyivSevastapol 950.50
    Greece    10DaysGreece  SummerGreeceHistoryThessalonikiLarissa  900.80
    Thailand    8DaysThailand   NatureAnimalFunKanchanaburiKhonKhaenMaeSot  750.30
    Malaysia  5DaysMalaysia DeliciousFoodGetawayPenangButterworth    450.60        
    Vietnam 5DaysVietnam    HistoricalVietnam   650.50 
    Myanmar   5DaysMyanmar   CulturalHistoryMyanmarYangonNaypidaw   590.30 
    Cambodia    7DaysCambodia   ExploreDifferentCultureBattambangtoPhnomhPenhtoSiemReap 780.20    
    Laos  5DaysLaos HistoryandCultureInVientieneThakhekXamNuea   500.85
    EastTimor   4DaysEastTimor  CampingRaftingAndHiking 600.35
    Indonesia   4DaysIndonesia  CultureNatureYogyakartaBandungAndWestJakarta    540.65
    France  10daysFrance    HistoricCultureNatureofStrasbourgBordeauxAndParis   1250.15
    Kazakhstan  8DaysKazakhstan HistoryCultureExperienceinAlmatyAndArtobeAndArkalyk 950.20
    Austria 8DaysAustria    CultureAndHistoryViennaSalzburgInnsbruck    900.30
    Italy   7DaysItaly  FoodNatureRomeMilanFlorence 900.20
    Spain   7DaysSpain  HistoryArtBarcelonaMadridValencia   850.10
    Portugal    6DaysPortugal   SeafoodandCultureLisbonAndPorto 820.30
    Switzerland 8DaysSwizterland    WinterAdventureZurichBaselGeneva    1150.20
    Norway  7DaysNorway CultureNatureNorthernLightsThroughOsloBergenAndTromso   950.15
    Sweden  7DaysSweden HistoryArtsFromStockholmUppsalaAndLinkoping 980.20
    Finland 8DaysFinland    NatureArtsOfHelsinkiOuluVaasa   1020.30
    Egypt   8DaysEgypt  PyramidAdventureLuxorCairoAlexandra 950.20
```

List Tab delimiter explanation of objects in txt file

```
    Index[0] of the list is country name.
    Index[1] of the list is travel package name.
    Index[2] of list is travel package description.
    Index[3] of list is travel package price. 
    Between each parameter in the list in the text file is a tab space to separate each element from another.
```

Error for exception is:

```
    Exception has occurred: IndexError
    list index out of range
    File "x:\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\courseNAME\modulename\Assignment 1\XXXXXXX.py", line 69, in <module>     tp = TravelPackage(lineParts[0],lineParts[1],lineParts[2],float(lineParts[3]))
```

The code is as follows.

```
    L62: f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"inputtravelPackages.txt"))
    L63: lines = f.readlines()
    L64: f.close()
    L65: packages=[]
    L66: for line in lines:
    L67: #print(line)
    L68: lineParts = line.split("\t")
    L69: tp = TravelPackage(lineParts[0],lineParts[1],lineParts[2],float(lineParts[3]))
```

I have referred to these 2 links but was unable to implement them.

1. [Stretchies Link index out of range python](https://www.stechies.com/fix-list-index-out-range-python/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CList%20index%20out%20of%20range,indexes%20of%20list%20elements%20properly)
2. [stackoverflow question of python indexerror list out of range while in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146809/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-while-in-for-loop)

Does anyone know how to resolve error. Do let me know if you need any more code from this code base too.
Thank you.

Comment: first read a good book about Python programming

Comment: The most possible reason of the error: trying to get different parts of the splitted empty line. It is better to check if each line in the loop has data.

Comment: @SergeyShubin: thanks! Ok will try to do those checks of line for data.

Comment: @rioV8: ok which python books do you recommend?